# Product Site Class Structure Suggestion

Tags: c#, activerecord

I am creating a product website which have products and product categories, I have created the following classes:

```
public abstract class Product 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatagoryId { get; set; }
}

public class DryFruits : Product
{
    public decimal WeightInGrams { get; set; }
    public decimal RatePerGram { get; set; }
}

public class DryFruitsPacks : Product
{
    public string PackName { get; set; }
    public decimal PackWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal PackPrice { get; set; }

}
```

I want a method `AddProduct()`, which must be present in every class derived from product and adds that product to the database.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you asking, what part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: this is what i tried as of now, i want to add products to the database, and want to make it sure every derived class from product should have addproduct, thats what i am trying to achieve @CodeCaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Product : IAddProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatagoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual void Add(Product p)
    {
       //Save to db
    };
}
public class DryFruits : Product
{
    public decimal WeightInGrams { get; set; }
    public decimal RatePerGram { get; set; }

    public override void Add(Product p)
    {
      //Save to db
    }
}

public interface IAddProduct
{
   void Add(Product product)
}

Public class SomeClass
{
  Product product = new DryFruits()
   {
     ProductName = "Nut";
     WeightInGrams = 0.01; 
   }
     private IAddProduct _saveIt;
    _saveIt.Add(product) 
}

Public class SomeOtherClass
{
  Product product = new Product()
   {
     ProductName = "Orange";
   }
 private IAddProduct _saveIt;
 _saveIt.Add(product) 
}
```

I always consider abstract classes to be a poor man's version of an interface. Even with the code above it fits the purpose of the SO's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an abstract class to you base Product class. and override it in your derived classes.

```
public abstract class Product 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatagoryId { get; set; }

    public abstract void Save();
}
public class DryFruits : Product
{
    public decimal WeightInGrams { get; set; }
    public decimal RatePerGram { get; set; }
    public override void Save()
    {
        //save the product
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should you pass the product to the function as parameter?

Comment: Just to point out that an abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Won't the abstract `Save()` cause redundancy for database access across the various derived classes?

Comment: @CodeCaster well, that depends on what architecture `KmrRaz` wants to implement and what technologies he uses

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes. When you create a derived class like DryFruits or DryFruitsPacks , you must provide an override method for all abstract methods in the abstract class. The AddProduct() method in both derived classes satisfies this requirement.

Override
Int field. An abstract class can have an instance field in it. The derived classes can access this field through the base syntax..

Int
Cannot instantiate abstract class. The important part of an abstract class is that you can never use it separately from a derived class.

```
   public abstract class Product 
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public int ProductCatagoryId { get; set; }

        public abstract void AddProduct(params object[] arguments);

    }
```

[Abstract methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: what about the parameter, how AddProduct() knows what to add?? @Midhun Mundayadan

Comment: Hopefully the SO understands he cannot: Product product = new Product(); which fundamentally make sense.